# How to get bean of an implementation by giving the interface name

Tags: java, spring

In Google Guice, we can define an interface and implementation as follows:

```
@ImplementedBy(MyImplementation.class)
interface MyInterface {
    ....
}

class MyImplementation implements MyInterface {

}
```

And if we use:

```
injector.getInstance(MyInterface.class);
```

an instance of the MyImplementation is returned as it knows MyImplementation implements MyInterface.

Is there an similar way in Spring to achieve this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring you can annotate your implementation with one of the annotations in the org.springframework.stereotype package e.g. @Service.

If you then use classpath [scanning](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning) to pick up your implementation you can obtain an instance of your interface from the bean store.